# RallyChart with the type being pie

Tags: rally

I am trying to connect a RallyChart using the type specifier set to pie with a Rally.data.custom.Store.  When the RallyChart has the type set to column or is blank, the data shows correctly.  When the type is set to pie, I get a pie with all 0%s returned.

Here's what my store looks like:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
    data: mySeries,
    fields: [
        { name: 'WorkItems', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Count', type: 'int' }
    ]
});
```

Here's what my chart configuration function looks like:

```
_buildChart: function(myStore) {
this.myChart = Ext.create('Rally.ui.chart.Chart', {
    height: 400, 
    store: myStore,
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Count',
        dataIndex: 'Count'
    }],
    xField: 'WorkItems',
    chartConfig: {
        chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
        text: 'Work Breakdown in Selected Sprint'
        },
        tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
});
this.add(this.myChart);
}
```

My data incoming looks like:
    ['Defects', 4],
    ['Feature A', 4]
    ['Feature B', 4]

Any ideas why column charts can show it, but pie cannot?

Comment: Are you using 2.0p5 or the recently released 2.0rc1?  I ask because there are some significant differences in Rally.ui.chart.Chart between the two versions.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add it.  I'm using 2.0p5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet this is a bug in the 2.0p5 version of the chart.  We just released version 2.0rc1 of the SDK which includes a better version of the chart.  The following code example shows how to create a pie with your data and [Rally.ui.chart.Chart](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.chart.Chart) in 2.0rc1:

```
//from inside your app
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallychart',
    height: 400,
    chartData: {
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
               ['Defects', 4], ['Feature A', 4], ['Feature B', 4]
            ]
        }]
    },
    chartConfig: {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        xAxis: {},//must specify empty x-axis due to bug
        title: {
            text: 'Work Breakdown in Selected Sprint'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note it is no longer necessary to create an intermediate store to pass to the chart- you can simply pass in your series as part of the chartData config.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!  Thanks for the example, I'll try it right away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Only comment to add for people trying to reproduce this is that there is a comma missing in  the data field. ['Defects', 4], ['Feature A', 4] ['Feature B', 4] should be ['Defects', 4], ['Feature A', 4], ['Feature B', 4]